# Fetch all the file names from blob storage which came on particular day using python/pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have multiple files in my blob storage , I want to fetch only the file names in form of a list which came on certain day.

for ex: blob strage has all files like

```
files  Modified
abc    8/22/2022, 1:34:16 AM
bdg    9/12/2022, 2:34:12 AM
hgf    9/12/2022, 5:34:12 AM
```

i need to fetch all the files which came on 9/12/2022
how to achieve this using python/pyspark?

Comment: Are you using Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's file name format, but try this -

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

spark.read.format(file_format).load(path).withColumn('file_name', F.input_file_name())
```

Then filter the `df` by the relevant date.

Comment: what if I have files in multiple formats?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi the code should fetch the file name for each and every row in the data., even if you have dozens of files.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. That makes sense. Can you please take a look at my following question as well? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/75168910/2225030