# Loop through RDD elements, read its content for further processing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a folder that contains `n` number of files.

I am creating an RDD that contains all the filenames of above folder with the code below:

```
fnameRDD = spark.read.text(filepath).select(input_file_name()).distinct().rdd)
```

I want to iterate through these `RDD` elements and process following steps:

1. Read content of each element (each element is a filepath, so need to read content throgh SparkContext)
2. Above content should be another RDD which I want to pass as an argument to a Function
3. Perform certain steps on the RDD passed as argument inside called function

I already have a Function written which has steps that I've tested for Single file and it works fine
But I've tried various things syntactically to do first 2 steps, but I am just getting invalid syntax every time.

I know I am not supposed to use `map()` since I want to read a file in each iteration which will require `sc`, but `map` will be executed inside worker node where `sc` can't be referenced.

Also, I know I can use `wholeTextFiles()` as an alternative, but that means I'll be having text of all the files in memory throughout the process, which doesn't seems efficient to me.

I am open to suggestions for different approaches as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly other, more efficient ways to do it but assuming you already have a function `SomeFunction(df: DataFrame[value: string])`, the easiest would be to use [`toLocalIterator()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator) on your `fnameRDD` to process one file at a time. For example:

```
for x in fnameRDD.toLocalIterator():
  fileContent = spark.read.text(x[0])
# fileContent.show(truncate=False)
  SomeFunction(fileContent)
```

A couple of thoughts regarding efficiency:

1. Unlike [`.collect()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect), `.toLocalIterator()` brings data to driver memory one partition at a time. But in your case, after you call `.distinct()`, all the data will reside in a single partition, and so will be moved to the driver all at once. Hence, you may want to add `.repartition(N)` after `.distinct()`, to break that single partition into N smaller ones, and avoid the need to have large heap on the driver. (Of course, this is only relevant if your list of input files is REALLY long.)
2. The method to list file names itself seems to be less than efficient. Perhaps you'd want to consider something more direct, using FileSystem API for example like in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data/list-delete-files-faster).

Comment: I was able to solve this with `For loop` & `RDD.collect()` but looking at you answer now, I believe I should use `toLocalIterator()` & `repartition()` as well. I'll try this for sure & will accept as answer once it works successfully. Also, I was aware that my approach to get filenames was hardly efficient, but was not able to find any alternatives. Thank you for the suggesting an article as well. You've earned this upvote!

Comment: Glad it helped. Using `.collect()` is hardly a "Spark way" to do things. Ultimately, I think you should consider converting your SomeFunction into something that can be used in `df.foreachPartition()` or `df.mapPartitions()`.

Comment: Instead of function, would it be better if I add those steps inside `For` loop itself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, and can't comment without better understanding what you're doing with individual file contents, sorry. Perhaps you can ask another question and provide more details there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for recursive file lookup,

`spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").text(filepathroot)`

if you point this to the root directory of your files, spark will traverse the directory and pick up all the files that sit under the root and child folders, this will read the file into a single dataframe

Comment: Thank you for the response but if this is keeping all the files in the Memory at the same time then that is exactly I'm trying to avoid here. I have a dataframe/RDD that contains filenames of all the files I want to read but the problem I am facing is to iterate through above DF/RDD, read file and perform operations on them.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi Spark is an in memory processing framework. If you're worried that all the files will be stored in memory in the driver then this will not be the case, if you read this in using the method above, data will be sent out to the workers for processing. If you read the files iteratively or do your transformation iteratively like with a for loop then it will definitely be read into the driver.

Comment: I know that the data will be distributed across the nodes, but I've a million files into directory & I don't want to load all the content of all the files at once. I think reading files sequentially into dataframe/rdd, it'll also distribute the content across node as well. And this would be more efficient in terms of Memory Utilization also. Am I missing any points here? I'm quite new to Spark tbh.